# "Server Error in '/' Application." in MVC4 when I create new folder with new view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am fairly new in MVC4. I'm working with C# Razor view engine using Entity Framework.

I wanted to add new view model that incorporated multiple models (obviously). But I needed a new view. So I created new folder inside Views named "MasterView" with a sample Index.cshtml inside, linked it inside _Layout.cshtml with

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Klick me", "Index", "MasterView")</li>
```

and when I ran my application, all the default links worked except that one (**Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.** ). Am I missing some permission for that page inside some project file? How do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Get Started with MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you link to Actions inside Controllers rather than pages/views.

In this case you would need a MasterViewController (in the Controllers folder) with an Index action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    return View();
}
```

This will render and return your Index.cshtml file.

Comment: Damn, the names weren't the same, oh God I feel so dumb. Thank you.